# Is there a way to Convert .fpf (FLIR Public Format) Files to JPEG or CSV?"

Tags: image, flir

I'm new to the field of thermal image processing and I'm working with a database that contains files in the .fpf (FLIR Public Format) format. I would like to know if there's a way to convert these .fpf files into more common formats like JPEG or CSV.

I've searched online, but I haven't found a clear solution for performing this conversion. Could someone please guide me on how I can achieve this? If there's any library, software tool, or process that I can follow, I would greatly appreciate any help provided.

I tried using the Thermal Studio software, ImageJ, and attempted to read the files in Python, but so far, nothing has worked